# Invalid controller specified (public) - Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a Zend Framework project. I got errors when I run the project.

*Invalid controller specified (public)*

Trace:

D:\MQuan\xampp\htdocs\usvn\library\Zend\Controller\Front.php:954    Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard::dispatch
D:\MQuan\xampp\htdocs\usvn\public\index.php:5   Zend_Controller_Front::dispatch

How to resolve it?

Comment: you get that error if you access your website? how do you call it? what is the controller? based on the error above, you have an invalid controller

Comment: Can we have *at least* the URL you try to access your project with?

Comment: You should check url which you are requesting matches correctly with your app configuration and controller action access path like [module/]controller/action